# Cropping a video in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, video

I need to crop a specific area of a video in MATLAB to be replayed and saved as that specific area. Currently I only know of a way to separate all the frames, crop them, and then put them back together as a video - is there an easier way or tool to crop a video in MATLAB or am I just going to have to rely on frame-by-frame cropping?

Comment: Use a system tool to use it within [MATLAB with `!`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html) maybe? To perform the cropping itself, something like this could help? - http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg

Comment: It's very bad form to delete a question which has answers. Please undelete the post you just deleted and provide us the information we need to actually provide what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab is generally horrible for video processing. I would recommend using a generic video editor. If you have to use matlab, there are a couple of toolboxes on [fileexchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7215-movie-editor) which will serve your purpose (for short videos in the most generic formats and also require image toolbox).

> Description
>   With Movie Editor you can: 
>   - Load movies (avi's only) 
>   - Cut movies 
>   - Crop movies 
>   - Split movies into separate color layers 
>   - Rotate movies 
>   - Save movies as avi or mpg (thanks to David Foti) 
>   - Save independent frames as bmp, jpg, png, and tif 
>   - You can always stroll through the movie using the slider and edittext underneath the image (maybe somebody can combine it with the 'Interactive MATLAB Movie Player' of Don Orofino. 
>   Maybe you can add a function? The user interface is pretty self-explanatory. But questions are welcome. An example of a before- and after-movie are added to the zip-file.

Comment: I really had hoped not get this answer but you're probably right. I can't use a different program so I'll just have to use the frame-by-frame method if I can figure it out. Thanks

Comment: I agree.  Do not use MATLAB to edit videos. Use a dedicated solution that is designed to do that for you, like Adobe After Effects.  There are also various free solutions out there such as the infamous `ffmpeg`.  Divakar's link above in the comments stream should help.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code that I wrote a while ago to process video files. Before executing this file save the ROI1.m file in the path.

```
%frame by frame processing of video files
clear all;
close all;
clc;
mov=VideoReader('C:\Users\Syd_R\OneDrive\Desktop\entrap\holo_bright_10_MMStack_Pos0.ome.avi');
vidFrames=read(mov);
nFrames=mov.NumberOfFrames;

A=vidFrames(:,:,1);

for fr=1:nFrames
    
    set(0,'DefaultFigureVisible','off')
    elseX=vidFrames(:,:,fr); 
     
if exist('position')==0
ROI1
else
imshow(elseX)
I2 = imcrop(elseX,[position(:,1) position(:,2) position(:,3) position(:,4)]);
end


mycell_h(fr)={I2};

end

close all;
set(0,'DefaultFigureVisible','on')
```

```
% This file should be saved (as ROI1.m) in the same path as this file will be called while executing the main file

% ROI
if exist('A')==1;
figure, imshow(A);
h = imrect(gca,[10 10 512 512]); 
 position = wait(h); % returns coordinates in "position" when user doubleclicks on rectangle
figure, imshow(A)
I2=imcrop(A,position);
    phROI2=I2;
    figure(11);
    imshow(phROI2);
    imwrite(phROI2, 'roi', 'tiff')
end;
```

The cropped frames will be saved in the cell [mycell_h]. To view the cropped frames, for example:

```
imshow(mycell_h{1,1})
```